# IOS 7 system fonts some times normal, some times bold, some times italic

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, ios7, uilabel

I am developing an IOS application. I always use system fonts for UILabel. But they appear sometimes bold and sometimes italic on some IOS 7 devices. I added a screenshot. You can see some lines normal and some lines bold. But I've set the default system font on xib. What I'm doing wrong,

Thanks.

[image: xib uilabel font]

[image: Bold and normal font]

Comment: I think understand, The reason for this issue: Font Family is "Helvetica Nue". if I selected system font then I don't change to Helvetica Nue. I tried to "custom font" and select "Helvetica" then text field looks smooth. This may be bug of the Apple?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check which are the settings for **Vision** in **Accessibility** in those devices? Are they the same?

[image]*

As you may know, in iOS7 users are allowed to change some aspects in the system's font as size and weight.

To handle the proper notifications when users change this settings and manage your fonts properly, take a look to [Text Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH4-SW65) programming guide.

*Image source: http://osxdaily.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-font-hard-to-read-fix/

Comment: As he mentions the issue appears on the same device, not in different ones. Some rows show as bold, some others as normal.

Comment: Sorry, this line "But they appear sometimes bold and sometimes italic on some IOS 7 devices" may me look it that way.